# Attaching a debugger to Services.exe in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-8.1, windbg

I have tried attaching a debugger to Services.exe in Windows 8.1 but I consistently get "Access is denied". This is true even after making sure that WinDbg was run "As Administrator" (was launched with elevation).

Just for the sake of testing I tried creating a memory dump file from task manager and I get the same error.

I also tried creating a dump using Process Explorer from Sysinternals (ProcExp) and I got the same error.

[image: Here is the screenshot of services.exe it its process tree]

The above picture shows the process tree (viewed using procexp) in which services.exe is located. Interestingly we can create dump files for wininit.exe and svchost.exe but not for services.exe.

I had some colleagues test this out on Windows 7 and it works fine. For those on Windows 8.1 - they get the same behavior as I got.

I am wondering if this a change with Windows 8.1. I hope someone can comment on whether there is a way to enable us to attach a debugger to services.exe.

Comment: In Process Explorer, what is displayed in the "User Name" column? Is it possible to attach in non-invasive mode?

Comment: User Name column is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for all three processes shown in my question. It was not possible to attach WinDBG even in non-invasive mode.

Comment: You could try launching as system using `psexec -s`

Comment: with ProcessHacker I can create a dump of services.exe: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @magicandre1981: I got the same result with Processhacker on Windows 8.1

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: I got the same result when I tried psexec -s:
psexec -s "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe" -pn services.exe
yielded:
Cannot debug pid 664, Win32 error 0n5
    "Access is denied."
Debuggee initialization failed, Win32 error 0n5
    "Access is denied."
This is consistent with what I have seen so far.

Comment: ok, I tested in in Windows8 (6.2) here it works. In 8.1 (6.3) it fails with access denied.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks for testing magicandre1981! My hope is that some people can comment on this. This looks like something systematic with Windows 8.1 and if there are some workarounds to this. I know this a more Microsoft issue but hopefully such an issue is appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @shiveshsuman - Sorry that was my best bet but now that it's been confirmed and reproducible, I would try pinging the people at defragtools.com. Andrew Richards or Chad Beeder are generally very responsive and know the ins and outs of WinDbg.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Thanks Lieven: I am also raising it at MSDN let's see if someone from Micorosoft chimes in with some suggestions.

Comment: I have added an answer. After some more research: it turns out this is expected behavior due to services.exe being a protected process - the debugger must also be turned into a protected process (which is possible only using a workaround involving a kernel debugger by editing the EPROCESS block of the debugger process).

Answer (score 3):

OK, thanks everyone for your contributions and comments. After some more research: it turns out - services.exe is a protected process in Windows 8.1 and therefore this will not work directly. The debugger must also be turned into a protected process. One way is to use a Kernel debugger first:

http://www.overclock.net/t/1300855/going-deep-dumping-the-memory-of-a-protected-process

Comment: Could you please include the relevant parts of the linked article so that this answer remains useful even if the link is down? Thanks.

Comment: In Windows 8.1+, modify the `Protection` field of the `EPROCESS` structure, as described in Alex Ionescu's article [The Evolution of Protected Processes](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=97). For example, changing the debugger process protection value to 0x61 makes it a WinTcb Protected Light process, which is the same as csrss.exe and services.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to debug `svchost.exe` - am guessing you want to debug a service.

In general `svchost.exe` hosts multiple services within it. So first up, you should be running *just* your dersired service within a single service.

I haven't had to debug a service myself for years now. But I remember using these links for help:

a. [How to debug Windows services with Windbg (MSDN Blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/08/19/how-to-debug-windows-services-through-terminal-services-on-windows-2000.aspx)

b. [Debugging a Service Application (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/1d1e24d5-8b6b-4ed5-84ad-b73356168b10)

these can help - if you haven't looked at them already.

Comment: I am not interested in svchost.exe really. I am interested in debugging attempt to start (startup failure) of certain specific proprietary services. Since the usual "Image File Execution Option" using gflags was not working - I thought of attaching a debugger to services.exe and then automatically attaching to a child processing using .childdbg 1 in WinDbg. After observing the anomalous behavior between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 in being able to attach a debugger to services.exe and not finding any resource online on the topic I thought I could perhaps discuss it on stack overflow.